# How to validate an html5 form and show error tips on a button click?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button submit inside a form and just a normal button outside of it. I want to validate a form:

```
   function myButtonHandler(evt) {
    if (myForm.checkValidity()) {
      alert("yes");
    } else {
      alert("no");
    }
  }
```

This doesn't show the standard error tips inside of input elements when they're invalid when I click on a button -- ones shown by a browser when I click the submit button. How can I get these validation message to pop up when I click on my normal button when the form is invalid?

```
<form id="my_form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" required="true"/>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="go" />
</form>
```

No jquery.

Comment: Where is your code for the "normal" button?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add the code you've shown to a function that is set up as the click event callback for the normal button:

```js
var myForm = document.querySelector("form");         // reference to form
var btn = document.querySelector("[type='button']"); // reference to normal button

// Set up click event handling function for normal button
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (myForm.checkValidity()) {
    alert("yes");
  } else {
    alert("no");
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" required>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>

<button type="button">Check Validity</button>
```

If you just want to show the normal browser's validation errors, you can make the second button also a submit button. It's OK for the button to be outside of the form as long as you tie it back to the form with the `form` attribute.

```html
<form id="theForm">
  <input type="text" required>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>

<button type="submit" form="theForm">Check Validity</button>
```